# SSIS package is executing while modification done on source table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

i created a SSIS package using simple DFT and transferring files from OLEDB source to OLEDB destination. When i am adding new column in my source table package is still getting executed successfully but i want my package to get failed. Could anyone suggest how to fix it.

Comment: You cant make it fail since it holds the metadata of your table, and you have not mapped your new column. Then it just proceeds as nothing was added. If you need to make it fail, you need a SQL script to write that it should fail when new rows are added to this table.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting a Table in OLEDB Source, the metadata of the table is mapped to the `OLEDB Source` component.

Each time you will run the package it will sends a `SELECT * From Table` command to the SQL server, and retrieve the data and it will map every column from the SQL table to the `OLEDB Source` column.

If a column is found in SQL and it is not defined in `OLEDB Source` it will be ignored. In the other hand, if a column is not found in SQL and it is defined in `OLEDB Source` it will throw an exception.

> The only way to validate metadata before running the package is to add an `Execute SQL Task` or `Script Task` to check the metadata before the `DFT` is executed.

**References**

- [SSIS OLE DB Source Editor Data Access Mode: “SQL command” vs “Table or view”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176930/ssis-ole-db-source-editor-data-access-mode-sql-command-vs-table-or-view/176933#176933)
- [OLEDB Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/ole-db-source)

Answer (score 0):

In the Control Flow area, add an `Execute SQL Task` before your DFT.
Set up the connection to your database and for your SQLStatement use the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (<define all columns currently in your OLEDB Source Table>)

INSERT INTO #temp 
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM <your OLEDB Source Table>
```

By using this "worst practice" insert syntax, you can cause a failure if your OLEDB Source Table has any columns added or removed.